# "Register" new full keymap (from xkbcomp) for use with input switchers

Tags: arch-linux, x11, kde, xkb

I have specified a full keymap with X11 xkb (replaced symbols, types and keycodes to unmap specific modifiers from the base pc files, etc.) in my own directory.

Using

```
xkbcomp -I/home/laura/codes/xkb/ /home/laura/codes/xkb/customKeymap.xkb $DISPLAY
```

I can load the new layout into use until I next reboot. However, this change is not reflected in the KDE UI which seems to reset the config whenever touched. Additionally, `setxkbmap -print` outputs the old keymap reflected by the UI regardless of my use of xkbcomp.

In the past, I would update `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` to include a reference to a new symbols file, which would cover the information needed to slot the new parts into "Map, Layout, Variant" of the UI / setxkbmap. I initially thought I could add reference in evdev.xml to an .xkm file output by xkbcomp when used with a directory in place of "$DISPLAY", but I couldn't find a way. This method seems only capable of concatenating a new symbols file with "pc", when ideally I'd like to define a whole keymap from scratch.

I need the new full keymap to be reflected in the UI partly for use with fcitx5, for switching between my custom keymap and an IME.

I've been through all the documentation of xkb and the relevant commands, but couldn't find reference to what I want to do. Where should I be looking?